# Using MetricsGraphics.js with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, graph, reactjs

I'm trying to use the graphing library [MetricsGraphs.js](http://metricsgraphicsjs.org/) with React.js. Like many graphing libraries, MetricsGraphics works by directly mutating the DOM. Unfortunately, this doesn't play very well with ReactJS. I've tried a bunch of different strategies, but I don't seem to be able to get past the fact that MetricsGraphs.js needs direct access to a DOM element that it can mutate. Have I overlooked anything, or is there no way to use MetricsGraphics.js with React without serious modifications to the library?

Comment: Look into getDOMNode(), which will allow you to access dom elements once the component already mounted. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#getdomnode

Comment: @Aqwis did you resolve this?

Comment: @Ben I recall resolving this through some ugly hacking in the end, but I unfortunately cannot recall exactly how as it's been several months since I last looked at the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ref` property of the component to get access to its DOM elements in React.

> These refs (references) are especially useful when you need to: find the DOM markup rendered by a component (for instance, to position it absolutely), use React components in a larger non-React application, or transition your existing codebase to React.

You can read more about `refs` in [React refs documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Here is an example which works in my projects today.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import MG from 'metrics-graphics';
import './node_modules/metrics-graphics/dist/metricsgraphics.css'; // path to the CSS of metricsgraphics

class Graph extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    MG.data_graphic({
      title: "Line Chart",
      description: "This is a simple line chart.",
      data: data,
      width: 600,
      height: 200,
      right: 40,
      target: this.target,
      x_accessor: 'date',
      y_accessor: 'value'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={(ref) => this.target = ref}></div>;
  }
}

export default Graph;
```

**update** Had to update `ref` to be a callback instead of a string to keep things simpler and to keep it working in the future due to few notes in the documentation:

[A note from Cautions section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions)

> If you want to preserve Google Closure Compiler Crushing resilience, make sure to never access as a property what was specified as a string. This means you must access using `this.refs['myRefString']` if your ref was defined as `ref="myRefString"`.

[A note from the ref String Attribute section](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute)

> Although string refs are not deprecated, they are considered legacy, and will likely be deprecated at some point in the future. Callback refs are preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Note that string refs are deprecated so you should use

```js
class Graph extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {

    MG.data_graphic({
      title: "Line Chart",
      description: "This is a simple line chart.",
      data: data,
      width: 600,
      height: 200,
      right: 40,
      target: this.elem,
      x_accessor: 'date',
      y_accessor: 'value'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={el => {if (el){this.elem = el}}}></div>;
  }
}

export default Graph;
```